# How to redirect to /home/, when matches (index.html)

Tags: django, django-models

I am using Django 1.4 for my project Builder

If I get a request like http://xxx.xx.xx:8000/index.html, how can I redirect to /home/?

Comment: Are you sure you want to leave this Job to you Webapp, not your Webserver (nginx etc...)?

Answer (score 1):

Redirect all /index.html requests to /home/ using `generic.simple.redirect_to`

```
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

urlpatterns = patterns('',   
    (r'^index.html$', redirect_to, {'url': '/home/'}),
    (r'^/home/$', 'myapp.views.my_home_view'),
)
```

Comment: you don't need `/` before `home`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an url to your urlconf

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    (r'^index\.html$', 'myapp.views.my_home_view'),
    ...
)
```

**EDIT**

An alternative option is to make use of the [`django.contrib.redirects`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/redirects/?from=olddocs/) app, and add an entry via the admin that redirects from `index.html` to `home/`. This is quicker and more configurable

Comment: I already tired, but it doesn't work. Then I understand that "." in index.html matches any character. (python re)

Comment: just escape it. (I've also added the quicker and more configurable alternative)

Comment: Having redirects will also be better for SEO, as the same page will not be seen under different URLs...

Comment: escaping the "." not working. 404 error and It redirects to http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8000/^$

Comment: Have you made sure it's above any other urls that might be matched before it in the urlpatterns? The redirects app is a better solution btw

Answer (score 0):

Use `redirect_to` method of `generic.simple`:

from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^home/$', 'yourapp.views.home', name='home'),
    (r'^index.html$', redirect_to, {'url': '/home/'}),
)
```